# Значение переменное после передачи intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Delo()было равно -4 до передачи интента:

```
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int otvet = delo();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

            intent.putExtra("a1",otvet);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

После передачи интента delo() становится равно:`No such instance method: 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.delo'`
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Для начала показать, что Вы делаете после передачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все проблемы были устранены нужно было добавить: `String.valueOf(otvet)`